# PyQt5 и Pyside2 проблема в запуске дизайна программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, qt-designer

Не могу запустить программу пишет отсутствует `file.rc`. Что это и как починить

**file.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>961</width>
    <height>565</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>-90</y>
     <width>961</width>
      <height>731</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">image:url(:/newPrefix/d.png)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>710</x>
      <y>9</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
                background-color: rgb(22.745098%, 26.6666667%, 36.8627451%);
}

QPushButton:hover{
    background-color: silver;
}
    </string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>войти</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="file.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**file.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

import file_rc

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(961, 565)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(0, -90, 961, 731))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(u"image:url(:/newPrefix/d.png)")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(720, 9, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
           "    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
           "    background-color: silver;\n"
"}\n"
       "    ")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", 
u"\u0432\u043e\u0439\u0442\u0438", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

**main.py**

```
import rc_icons
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from ui import Ui_MainWindow

#Create applicatio
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#Create form and init UI
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

#Hook logic
def bp():
    ui.lineEdit.setText("log in")
def bp1():
    ui.lineEdit.setText("register")
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( bp )
ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect( bp1 )

#Run main loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**file.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>d.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста модуль `file.qrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я проверил ваш пример, все работает.

1. `pyuic5 file_1181916.ui -o file_1181916_ui.py`    # -> file_1181916_ui.py

Обратите внимание, что я переименовал файл `file.ui` в файл `file_1181916.ui`
В результате этого действия мы получаем - `file_1181916_ui.py`

2. `pyrcc5 file.qrc -o file_rc.py`                  # -> file_rc.py

В результате этого действия мы получаем - `file_rc.py` .
Это ваш файл ресурсов.

Внимание. Обратите внимание, что я подставил свое изображение `im.png`,
т.е. в `file_1181916.ui` и `file.qrc` заменил `d.png` на `im.png`.

3. Запускаем `main_1181916.py`. Все.

**main_1181916.py**

```
import sys
#import rc_icons                                # ??? rc_icons
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from file_1181916_ui import Ui_MainWindow
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

#Create applicatio
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#Create form and init UI
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()


#Hook logic
def bp():
#    ui.lineEdit.setText("log in")                # ??? lineEdit
    print(f'def bp(): log in')
    
#def bp1():
#    ui.lineEdit.setText("register")
    
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)
# ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(bp1)            # ??? pushButton_2

#Run main loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**pyuic5 file_1181916.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>961</width>
    <height>565</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>-90</y>
     <width>961</width>
      <height>731</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">image:url(:/newPrefix/im.png)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>710</x>
      <y>9</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
                background-color: rgb(22.745098%, 26.6666667%, 36.8627451%);
}

QPushButton:hover{
    background-color: silver;
}
    </string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>войти</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="file.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**file.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>im.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

У вас должен быть, помимо `ui`, файл ресурсов (`qrc`).

**Если его нет, то создайте. Это можно сделать в дизайнере через окно ресурсов**

Сделал [по этой инструкции](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26512031/5909792) (скрины мои):

1. Создание файла ресурсов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Создание префикса и добавление файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Указание файла из ресурсов виджету:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[А для ручной генерации ресурсов из файла ресурсов, попробуйте в консоли выполнить команду:](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/qrcfiles.html#generating-a-python-file)

```
pyside2-rcc file.qrc -o rc_icons.py
```

После в `main.py`, до других импортов, сделайте:

```
import rc_icons
```

Comment: ошибка Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/geoko/PycharmProjects/schoolproject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 146, in _import
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Не найдена указанная процедура.

Comment: @Ribl, странная ошибка, какая-то проблема с dll, скорее всего переустановка pyqt5 поможет

Comment: а как переустоновить я писал в терминал Pip install pyqt5 несколько раз писало что типо установленно

Comment: @Ribl, сначала удалите через `pip uninstall pyqt5`, после поставьте заново