# Ошибка при импорте ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, windows-7

Есть структура

[image]

В файле `starting_window` код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from resources.start_win import Ui_MainWindow


class StartingWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartingWindow, self).__init__()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    start_win = StartingWindow()
    start_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

При запуске через терминал - `python interface\starting_window` возникает ошибка
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'`.

При поиске решения обнаружил, что код работает при запуске через `Run/Debug Configuration` с отметкой "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH". Без этой отметки такая же ошибка.

То есть, для того, чтобы запустить код через терминал нужно добавить путь до папки `resources` в `PYTHONPATH`.

`sys.path.append(...)` не работает. Папка добавляется, но модуль не находится.
`mark as sourse root` не работает
`add to interpreter path` тоже

Может ли это быть ошибка в Pycharm или же это я туплю?

UPD:
Код работает, если запустить через терминал с флагом -m или же если создать файл в корневой папке и в нём прописать импорт файла starting_window.py.
Есть ли другой способ запуска, например, прописав что-то где-то в настройках PyCharm?

Comment: Пробуйте запускать как модуль: `python -m interface.starting_window`

Comment: @insolor с флагом -m код работает. Хочу понять как можно заставить работать без флага -m. Рабочий способ запуска(через run/debug) уже есть

Comment: Дело ваше. Но вообще, так как у вас код уже организован как набор модулей внутри пакетов, то логично и запускать их как модули - с флагом -m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я предложу вам следующее:

- вот структура вашего проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- внимание, модули, которые я разложил по папкам
  взяты из поста [PyQt5 и Pyside2 проблемма в запуске дизайна программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181916/pyqt5-%d0%b8-pyside2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b/1182472#1182472)
- создаем модуль, например `projectAist.py`,
  который содержит одну строку `import interface.main_1181916`
  и его в папку `Aist`
- запускаем с любого места `python D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\Aist\projectAist.py`

---

**projectAist.py**

```
import interface.main_1181916        # !!! interface.
#      ^^^^^^^^^                     # !!!
```

**main_1181916.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


from resources.file_1181916_ui import Ui_MainWindow    # !!! resources.
#    ^^^^^^^^^^                                        # !!!

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

def bp():
    print(f'def bp(): log in')
 
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**file_1181916_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(961, 565)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -90, 961, 731))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("image:url(:/newPrefix/im.png)")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 9, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"                background-color: rgb(22.745098%, 26.6666667%, 36.8627451%);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}\n"
"    ")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "войти"))


import resources.file_rc                                                    # !!! resources.
#      ^^^^^^^^^                                                            # !!!
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @S-Nick работает. Похоже на обходной способ флага -m

Answer (score -2):

пуск-поиск-система-изменить параметры-дополнительно-параметры среды-path-изменить-создать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде бы вопрос был не о том, как добавить значение в переменные окружения. Для меня очевидно, что автор вопроса знает как это сделать.

Comment: Уже добавлена инфа в  переменную path таким образом